# How to limit the number of files that the app can receive through sharing intent

Tags: android, file, android-intent, share

In my app i registered an activivty with this intent-filter :

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

but i would like to limit the number of files that can be shared each time (10 for example in whatsapp) already when the user chooses my app from the list (instead of alerting inside the activity) ..

Is there any attribute for that?

thanks in advance and sorry for my english :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any attribute for that?

No, sorry. While you are welcome to have a limit, you have no way of advertising it, let alone forcing activities that invoke yours to abide by that limit. Hence, you will have to handle the limit yourself, or eliminate the limit.

Comment: Thank you sir, i will handle it right at the beginning of "onCreate"